# How can I use clearRect() without erasing other objects I have?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a moving object and so it doesn't leave a trail behind I am using the clearRect(). However I can't remove everything in the canvas because that would remove my other object (which is the goal for the player to collect.)

```
  var playerX = 350;
  var playerY = 450;
  function coin(posX, posY, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'gold';
    ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height); //this is what I don't want to clear
  }
  function player() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 50, 50);
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  function random(min, max) {
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
     return x;
  }
  function moveLeft() {
    playerX -= 5;
    player();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
  }
  function moveRight() {
    playerX += 5;
    player();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveLeft);
  }
  player();
  coin(random(5, 650), random(5, 250), 50, 50);
  </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is make a single animation function that would call itself recursively.

```
function animate(){
  canvas.clearRect()
  // draw everything here
  window.requestanimationframe(animate)
}

animate()
```